# Rails 4 ajax: request being submitted too many times

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to incorporate AJAX into my rails application when a user clicks the 'add to order' button. I want the item to get added to the order without the page reloading. When I click 'add to order', the ajax request gets sent multiple times resulting in many items being added to my order instead of just 1 item.

Here is my link_to tag that triggers an ajax request:

```
 <%= link_to ' ', :method => :post, :remote => true %>
```

Here is the code for my 'products' controller and the 'buy' action:

```
def buy
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to ' ' }
    format.js
end
```

From my understanding, the default rails action will be to load the app/views/products/buy.js.erb file and execute the commands in that file.
Here is what I have in that file:

```
$("#order-panel").html("").append("<%= j render 'order_summary' %>");
```

I am essentially overriding the previous html with the new template in this file:

```
_order_summary.html.erb
```

This partial contains the following code:

```
<div class="panel-heading">
  <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-tags'></span><span   class="text">Order Summary</span>
</div>
<div class="panel-body">
<% if current_order %>
    <% if current_order.total_items == 0 %>
        <div class="order-summary-text empty-order">Your order is empty.</div>
    <% else %>
        <div class="order-summary-text">yadayada</div>
        <div class="order-btns">
           <%= link_to ' ' %>
           <%= link_to ' ' %>
        </div>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Does anyone know why my multiple items are getting added instead of 1?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: in `buy` method add `end` end of it. extra `end` for `respond_to` method to close it.

Comment: Is it because users might be clicking too many times on production or does it also happen when you click on the link locally?

Comment: It happens when I click on the link locally.